# "These kids I tell you" or "kids I tell you" expression meaning

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, idioms, context

I have read them in few disconnected articles and in conversations but could not understand them completely.

"These kids I tell you" or "kids I tell you" expression meaning.

What do they mean ?

Comment: I had to smile when I read this.  I could hear it in my mother's voice. "Oy, these kids, I tell you, they're so lazy today."   I think "these kids" is what I was taught was called a topicalizer.  It introduces the topic.  "I tell you" indicates that the speaker is about to state an opinion.  I think there should be a comma between the two because they play different roles.

Comment: @AlMaki Yes; and the opinion may in fact left for the hearer to infer.

Comment: It is an elliptical shorthand for any of a number of possible complaints by elderly people about the current generation of adolescents. Quintus Horatius Flaccus in the first century B.C. recommended that any author who wished to create believable elderly characters should put such complaints in their mouths, so either the degeneration of the species has been ongoing for over two millennia or a jaundiced view is a symptom of senescence. I am betting on the latter, and boast no personal immunity from the condition.

Comment: @Brian Donovan: *These handheld devices the young kids have today! I tell you they're amazing!* The usage doesn't inherently imply "complaints".

Comment: The bound-together expression is "I tell you" or "I'm telling you." Whether the the subject of the telling is kids, money, politics, work, or something else, you could frame it as "[subject], I tell you..." And the construction "[subject], I tell you" conveys the idea "I am about to tell you something about [subject]."

Comment: Thanks @AlMaki @StoneyB @BrianDonovan @FumbleFingers @SvenYargs . Based on all your comments, I think I now understand it. I would attempt to word it : `Its meaning is more a bit on the complaining side, though a mild one instead of a serious one, referring to the natural (  expected ) mild negative side of something. Its exact meaning depends on the context; which generally follows this expression. It also tells that the speaker is trying to convey a self presumed state of having some past conviction and authority. ` Please correct me if I got it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

To me "These kids I tell you" is the *beginning* of a complaint or compliment about "these kids" followed by the explanation of your complaint or compliment so your next words would be:

> "These kids, I tell you, are driving me crazy!"

or

> "These kids, I tell you, are very mature for their age."

The "I tell you" is added in as emphasis, but then the rest is dropped just to leave it open for interpretation.